# EWS - Given an Appointment, get the owner's copy of the Appointment

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

Given an Appointment in EWS, is it possible to get the owner's copy?

For instance, if I am logged in as `user1`, I have `user1`'s copy of an Appointment that was created by `user2`, I have impersonation rights, and I want to edit `user2`'s copy of the Appointment, how can I obtain `user2`'s copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the  PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839502.aspx which will be set on both the Meeting invitation/update and the Appointment object to search for the Meeting in an Attendee or Orgainizer mailbox eg

```
Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment(service);
newAppointment.Subject = "Test Subject";        
newAppointment.Start = new DateTime(2016, 08, 27, 17, 00, 0);
newAppointment.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
newAppointment.EndTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
newAppointment.End = newAppointment.Start.AddMinutes(30);
newAppointment.Save();
newAppointment.Body = new MessageBody(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.BodyType.Text, "test");
newAppointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("attendee@domain.com");
newAppointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite ,SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
ExtendedPropertyDefinition CleanGlobalObjectId = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Meeting, 0x23, MapiPropertyType.Binary);
PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
psPropSet.Add(CleanGlobalObjectId);
newAppointment.Load(psPropSet);
object CalIdVal = null;
newAppointment.TryGetProperty(CleanGlobalObjectId, out CalIdVal);
Folder AtndCalendar = Folder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar,"attendee@domain.com"));
SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(CleanGlobalObjectId, Convert.ToBase64String((Byte[])CalIdVal));
ItemView ivItemView = new ItemView(1);
FindItemsResults<Item> fiResults = AtndCalendar.FindItems(sfSearchFilter, ivItemView);
if (fiResults.Items.Count > 0) {
    //do whatever
}
```

Comment: I've found a few issues with this approach.  First, all recurring events in a series have the same `PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId`, and second, sometimes `PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId` is null (I haven't figured out why).

Comment: You have instance information (Eg time/date) from the source so you will need to use that, if its a normal instance there is no Real appointment object to bind to it's only relative if its an exception. There should be GOID property on every appointment (Calendar won't work it and it something the calendar repair scans for and fixes) I would suggest you look at the objects with a Mapi editor.

Comment: @GlenScales Thank you for your answer. Do you know anything about deprecating `PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId`? Here is what [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/globalobjectid) about `GlobalObjectId`. What's the relationship between `PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId` and `GlobalObjectId`?

Comment: Haven't heard anything about it being depreciated, the doc your pointing is for the GetUserAvailbility operation in EWS so it has no real relevancy to it depreciation status. Search for PidLidCleanGlobalObjectId and PidLidGlobalObjectId in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocal/09861fde-c8e4-4028-9346-e7c214cfdba1 this explain the relationships.