# How can a delegate get a recurring master from the mailbox owner's Calendar folder with EWS Managed API?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, appointment

There is a planner app that reads appointments from the Exchange calendar located at `planner@exchange.com` account and does some business logic based on the appointment content. Users of the same Exchange server create their appointments and add `planner@exchange.com` as a Required Attendee. `planner@exchange.com` account has delegate rights to read from and write to user accounts' calendar events.

There is one case I am struggling with.
A user created a recurring daily event in its calendar from Feb 25 to Feb 28 (4 instances) but did not include `planner@exchange.com` calendar as a Required Attendee for the whole event, rather only for the single Feb 26 instance.

In the `planner@exchange.com` calendar such instance will be retrieved as an `Appointment` with `IsRecurring` set to `true` but `AppointmentType` set to `AppointmentType.Single`. For business logic I need to get a Recurring Master of a recurring event.

**How can I get a Recurring Master of the Feb 26's instance?**

Usual way to get a recurring master is explained in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-access-a-recurring-series-by-using-ews-in-exchange#get-related-recurrence-calendar-items-by-using-the-ews-managed-api)

```
recurrMaster = Appointment.BindToRecurringMaster(service, itemId, props);
```

Problem is that for a `AppointmentType.Single` event such method throws an exception with error code `ErrorCalendarCannotUseIdForOccurrenceId`

I have Feb 26 appointment's `ItemId` and organizer email address but I don't have organizer password therefore I cannot create another ExchangeServer instance to access the organizer calendar directly.

There is the [ExchangeService.FindItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.finditems?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=exchange-ews-api#overloads) method with many overloads, particularly:

`FindItems(FolderId, String, ViewBase)`

> Returns items from a target folder according to the associated search query with the specified preview page view.

`FindItems(FolderId, SearchFilter, ViewBase)`

But I could find any explanation neither on how to write a search query nor how to specify a search filter to get a Recurring Master event.

Could you please help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am quite new to EWS I could not formulate the question properly. Here is actually the same question, but formulated much clearer, and the answer [EWS - Given an Appointment, get the owner's copy of the Appointment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38271407/ews-given-an-appointment-get-the-owners-copy-of-the-appointment).
It worked for me.